# Why does my co-worker see a different Project file (*.csproj) using Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, csproj

I met a problem which is very strange, my company uses Visual Source Safe
to control version,but I found that my team's different member see the same .csproj file in VSS is not the same, it's very strange,can you help me? thanks!!

there is a file named IPRA.WinUi.Sal.Sra.csproj in VSS:

when Tom log on ,the file 'IPRA.WinUi.Sal.Sra.csproj' is :

```
<Reference Include="Ark.Client.WinUi, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\ARAF\BusinessFramework\Ark.Client.WinUi.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Ark.Common.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Ark.Controls.Business, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\ARAF\SystemFramework\Ark.Controls.Business.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But when leo log on,the same file 'IPRA.WinUi.Sal.Sra.csproj' is :

```
 <Reference Include="Ark.Client.WinUi, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\ARAF\BusinessFramework\Ark.Client.WinUi.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Ark.Common.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\ARAF\BusinessFramework\Ark.Controls.WinUi.dll</HintPath>
<Reference Include="Ark.Controls.Business, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\ARAF\SystemFramework\Ark.Controls.Business.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand the question. Could you give some more details?

Comment: I'm sure you know this but SourceSafe will cause you soooo many problems. We've just moved to TFS and it's like a breath of fresh air. See http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html and http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html if you're not familiar with the problems you'll hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He needs to do a get latest, try build tree option to get to your development folder. He might be getting files to the wrong folder, thus his files are not updated. Try verifying your working folder is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> but I found that my team's different
>   member see the same .csproj file in
>   VSS is not the same,

Team see the same cs project? Then wats the issue?

If the team is seeing different file then the other person has not checked in or you are not using the latest version. Always try to checkin when you leave and get the latest version when you start your work.